# JavaFX how to change value of existing text field upon Button press

Tags: javafx, textfield

I'm working on a GUI calculator and am having trouble modifying the text field at the top of the calculator when a button is pressed. My text field is labeled 'text', but in the listener class I'm having trouble referencing it. This is my listener class:

```
class ClearListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        calculator1.clear();
        text.setText(0.0);
    }
}
```

Obviously the reference to the TextField in the ClearListener class doesn't work because the scope doesn't include that class, but I'm not sure how else I would reference it.

I tried this:

```
public class UserInterfaceCalculator extends Application {
    private MemoryCalculator calculator1 = new MemoryCalculator();
    private String operator = null;
    private TextField text = new TextField("0.0");
    private Boolean equalsPressed = true;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
```

This fixes the scope issue, and the text field still shows correctly with the initial value of 0.0, but then the value doesn't change from 0.0 even when I set a new value in the listener classes upon a button press.

Comment: Could you show where you define the text field?

Comment: And we should provide you with a tutorial about scopes???

Comment: It's defined under "public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {" which I realize is the problem since it's not in the scope of this ClearListener class, but I'm not sure how I would get it there.

Comment: Could I create a private TextField under "public class UserInterfaceCalculator extends Application {" and then set the one in the primaryStage equal to it?

Comment: Nope that doesn't work. It compiles correctly, but the value of the text field doesn't change.

Comment: Why not use setOnAction  ex. button.setOnAction(event -> {
            calculator1.clear();
            text.setText(0.0);
        });